# Octave EIG class in C++, algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, octave, linear-algebra, eigen

I'm using `EIG` class of Octave in my C++ code. Actually, it works good. The only minor issue which I have is that it determines algorithm automatically based on the argument list of `EIG` constructor. I was wondering if there is a way to determine algorithm for the `EIG` class. I noticed that there is an optional argument called `info`, I looked into C++ source code (on the following link) to see if it relates to algorithm but I couldn't figure it out.

http://octave.sourceforge.net/doxygen/html/d6/d42/EIG_8cc_source.html

I'm using Octave 3.6.1 with Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: Are you aware of the fact, that you have to release your code under the GPL if you use GNU Octave calsses in your program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I researched on topic. Apparently Octave has no option to determine the algorithm of `eig` command. But MATLAB has two options of `'chol'` algorithm and  `'qz'` algorithm for badly-conditioned matrices.

If you want to calculate the Eigen values & vectors of ill-conditioned matrices in C++, you can implement DGGEV or DGGEVX routines of LAPACK.